# Gspread - Find a value and display the cell to the right

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to find a tag in my google spreadsheet ("1" or "0") to allow a folder creation tool to pull project names that will be used to create the folder. I am able to use the find/findall function to find the tag but unfortunately I can only get the field value of the cell that's found instead of the cell to the left that holds the project name. Column C is either 0 or 1, Column B holds the project name. The google spreadsheet should function as a database here.

This seems pretty basic but I can't figure it out. Would appreciate any help.

```
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("keys.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
wks = client.open("Projects").sheet1

cell = wks.findall("1")

project = (cell.row, cell.col + -)
print(project)
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image or values?

Comment: Basically there are 3 rows. Project Name, Producer and "To be created" which has a 0 or a 1 depending on if it has been created already. Does that explain it better?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.